# In Android Studio Hedgehog, how can I remove all the non error yellow and grey warning highlights from the scrollbar?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, scrollbar, warnings

In Android Studio Hedgehog flutter project, how can I remove all the non error yellow and grey warning highlights from the scrollbar? I have already set customize highlighting level to Syntax only

As shown on attached image below

[image]